# Ubuntu GNOME Software Centre global light theme makes selected item unreadable. How to fix?

Tags: gnome, software-center, themes

[image: The selection is unreadable]

[image: The text looks odd]

Turning off Global Dark Theme in Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 makes selected item in the Software Center unreadable. Similar things happen in the Extensions page of GNOME Tweak Tool. I have tried disabling all the extensions.

**EDIT: I just tried this on Kali Linux 2.0 which was also running GNOME3 and the issue in the Tweak Tool seems to be absent there. I thus think it is most likely an issue with my specific display.**

**The one regarding the Software Center remains.**

Comment: have you got a copy of a light theme in you local home folder ~/.themes - maybe that is conflicting.

Comment: I'll check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this, and enter this from the terminal:

```
 dconf replace -f /org/compiz
 unity --reset-icon &disown
 sudo dkms-reconfigure unity
```

and it might work fine this way.